# Reshape large dataframe to wide dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to transform this dataFrame;

```
+----+-------+---+---
|col1|col2   |RC1|RC2
+----+-------+---+---
|A   |B      |  1|  0
|C   |D      |  1|  1
+----+-------+---+---
```

to this!

```
+----+-------+------+
|col1|col2   |newCol|
+----+-------+------+
|A   |B      |  RC1 |
|C   |D      |  RC1 |
|C   |D      |  RC2 |
+----+-------+---+
```

Tidyr seems to answer that well using the gather function, isn't there a possible solution with spark scala?

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+----+---+---+
|col1|col2|rc1|rc2|
+----+----+---+---+
|A   |B   |1  |0  |
|C   |D   |1  |1  |
+----+----+---+---+
```

Build expression.

```
scala> val colExpr = 
when($"rc1" === 1 && $"rc2" === 1,array(lit("RC1"),lit("RC2")))
.when($"rc1" === 1 && $"rc2" === 0, array(lit("RC1")))
.when($"rc1" === 0 && $"rc2" === 1, array(lit("RC2")))
```

Apply expression.

```
scala> 
spark.time { 
    df
    .select($"col1",$"col2",explode(colExpr).as("newcol"))
    .show(false) 
}

+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|newcol|
+----+----+------+
|A   |B   |RC1   |
|C   |D   |RC1   |
|C   |D   |RC2   |
+----+----+------+

Time taken: 914 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unpivot method `stack` to achieve this as given below,

```
val df=Seq(("A", "B", 1, 0), ("C", "D", 1, 1)).toDF("col1", "col2", "RC1", "RC2")

+----+----+---+---+
|col1|col2|RC1|RC2|
+----+----+---+---+
|   A|   B|  1|  0|
|   C|   D|  1|  1|
+----+----+---+---+

df.select($"col1", $"col2", expr("stack(2,'RC1', RC1, 'RC2', RC2) as (newCol,RC_VAL)")).where($"RC_VAL" =!= 0).drop("RC_VAL").show()

+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|newCol|
+----+----+------+
|   A|   B|   RC1|
|   C|   D|   RC1|
|   C|   D|   RC2|
+----+----+------+
```